# How to align the quotient when using polynom

Tags: vertical-alignment, polynom

I am using the `polynom` package to illustrate long division with polynomials. Typically, when I do those problems by hand, I have the first term in the quotient aligned with the first term in the dividend. However, as my code below will show, the alignment is essentially what I need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\polylongdiv{2x^4+7x^3+8x^2+5x+4}{x^3+x^2+x+1}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to align the 2 of the quotient with the 2 of the dividend?

Comment: Well as you could see the package sorts the polynomials belong to the degree or exponent in decreasing order. In this case the alignment is right. Perhaps the package documentation gives you an option for sort the polynomials in the way you are asking for.

Comment: I checked the manual and couldn't find any such option, unfortunately.

Comment: but... Why you want to align the polynomials in that way?

Comment: That is my personal preference and I wanted to know if it is possible. I am not unique in having that as my preference, searching polynomial division on the web yields many examples of the kind of alignment I am after.

Comment: Let's see if I understand, do you want that the `2` (of `2x+5`) is exactly above of `2` of `2x^4+7x^3+...`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \let\oldpld@SplitQuotient\pld@SplitQuotient
    \def\pld@SplitQuotient{\oldpld@SplitQuotient\def\pld@pattern{}}
    \polylongdiv{X^9-X^8-X^5+X^4+X+1}{X-1}
\end{document}
```

### Long Answer

After some experiments, one may notice that `polynom` leaves some holes while printing non-consecutive monomials.

[image]

The mechanism is that `polynom` uses `\pld@pattern` as a *placeholder*. Since the dividend is of degree 9, `\pld@pattern` is `X^9+X^8+...+1` (sort of).

[image]

It then starts to match `\pld@quotient` and `\pld@pattern`. In this case, `X^8` goes to `X^8` and `-X^4` goes to `X^4`. Same thing happens when `polynom` tries to print the dividend. That is why the `X^8` in quotient is aligned with `-X^8` in dividend.

To get over this, we need to replace the placeholder by a shorter one.

[image]

But then it would be *not so smart* if we have to assign the placeholder by hand. The good news is, replacing the placeholder by nothing forces `polynom` to (re)generate a shorter one. Now it should be what you want.

[image]

The remaining problem is where to replace it? Here I append a `\def\pld@pattern{}` after `\pld@SplitQuotient` just because `polynom` is about to print the quotient.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{polynom}
    \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \let\oldpld@SplitQuotient\pld@SplitQuotient
    \begin{figure}
        \polylongdiv{X^9-X^8-X^5+X^4+X+1}{X-1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \def\pld@SplitQuotient{\oldpld@SplitQuotient\def\pld@pattern{}}
        \polylongdiv{X^9-X^8-X^5+X^4+X+1}{X-1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \def\pld@SplitQuotient{\oldpld@SplitQuotient
            \def\pld@quotient{\pld@V{X}{9}+\pld@V{X}{8}+\pld@V{X}{7}+\pld@V{X}{6}+\pld@V{X}{5}+\pld@V{X}{4}+\pld@V{X}{3}+\pld@V{X}{2}+\pld@V{X}{1}+\pld@R 11}}
        \polylongdiv{X^9-X^8-X^5+X^4+X+1}{X-1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \def\pld@SplitQuotient{\oldpld@SplitQuotient\def\pld@pattern{}
            \def\pld@quotient{\pld@V{X}{8}+\pld@V{X}{7}+\pld@V{X}{6}+\pld@V{X}{5}+\pld@V{X}{4}+\pld@V{X}{3}+\pld@V{X}{2}+\pld@V{X}{1}+\pld@R 11}}
        \polylongdiv{X^9-X^8-X^5+X^4+X+1}{X-1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer!